# Embedding commercial fonts into websites

Tags: fonts, sifr, embedded-resource, cufon, typeface.js

Good evening ladies and gentlemen!

Searching for a cross-browser solution to embed commercial fonts
like HelveticaNeue or Univers etc. I found some promising approaches.

First of all I will enlist all found, modern and easy to use approaches here:

1. sIFR
2. Cufón
3. typeface.js
4. CSS3 font-face

sIFR is well known and kinda easy to implement, but as I know, not as
easy as it's Javascript-only siblings, Cufón and typface.js.

Cufón has caught my attention, as it renders a little bit better
than typeface.js, and creates smaller sized font-files. Apparently
there is no legal way to use it with any commercial font out there,
which is disallowed to be embedded into this kind of solution.

For typeface.js the same situation applies, just differing in the
fact, that it's not even able to convert fonts with a license, which
forbids to embed it into websites.

Last but not least there is this 'new' CSS property, called font-face,
which is incredibly easy to use, but for our loved IE we need to convert
the files into EOT (Embedable OpenType) files.

Therefore special CSS declarations are needed for IE, to be able to
use these fonts inside the browser.

The question is now:

What is the best approach to use such commercial fonts on websites?
Use free fonts only from now on with Cufón or convert all used fonts into EOT
files, and use them together with font-face?

Thanks for your well argumented answers, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after some hours research and testing I found a VERY
nice solution for embedding special fonts into websites.

Using the approach via CSS3 font-face is imho the best solution.

The only overhead-thing you have to do for IE, is to convert
your Truetype fonts (Unfortunately OTF is not working.) into
EOT files. Microsoft WEFT is a solution, but the BEST way
to do this, is to use the open-sourced tool 'ttf2eot', which
can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/

A web-based frontend can be found searching 'kirsle wizards' on Google.

The only thing to notice is browser support...

IE4,5,6,7,8 use the EOT files, while TTF support is only
provided by Firefox versions >= 3.1. About Safari and Opera
I'm not sure, but Safari 4 worked for me, and Opera 10 too.

(So Chrome doesn't support it I guess, due to usage of
an older webkit version?!)

Based on our agency's clients' tracking statistics "only"
15 to 20% of their visitors use incompatible browsers like
Firefox 2.0 or 3.0, older Safari or Opera versions or Chrome.

Comment: A note on font-embedding using the CSS3 font-face decleration: You still have to be sure, that the font-license allows embedding! As I know all Adobe fonts allow you, to do so. There is also a large palette of free high quality fonts out there on the web.

Comment: Thasmo: Are you sure Adobe supports embedding with CSS font-face? That would be great if that is the case. I have a bit difficult understanding their policies and exactly what "Licensed for Preview and Print Embedding" means: http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/legal/embeddingeula.html

Comment: Well, actually I'm not really sure - the licence information of Adobe is really hard to understand, in fact I don't know. You better go with real open fonts like the ones from the league of moveable types.

Comment: Yes I've been reading up on it and it is really confusing. Embedding in flash seems allowed. So using SIFR must be OK. Yes I wish I could use open fonts but this is not an option when a company already has a identity which incorporates a commercial font.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of this page has info on how to do it using straight HTML and CSS:
http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/text/font

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I was asking for was, what is the easiest and also most accurate, even seo-friendly and easiest maintainable and future-oriented way of doing this? =o)